# c# database little available memory

Tags: c#, database, windows-mobile-5.0

I am trying to update a database management system on a PPC (Pocket Pc, with less ram and Windows Mobile).
The old version of the database is based only on textfiles. 
I need a database management system which is fast and doesn´t need a lot of ram.
Also the system must work under Windows Mobile 5.0.
Any ideas?

Comment: does anyone use them, I am surprised? no offense though. Try SQLlite, I am sure it will suite your requirement and you will find it's older compatible version too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It is a very small (~400KB) DBMS for embedded operating systems. As it is open source you can always compile for your own platform, or use interop libraries as directed in [this](http://blog.tallan.com/2009/12/31/adding-sqlite-to-a-windows-mobile-application/) post.